# MySQL: Move data from one Table to another with unique idetifiers

Tags: mysql, sql, move

I am unsure how to use the UPDATE/WHERE statement in this case.

```
source_table
pid, source-text

dest_table
uid, dest-text, [many more]
```

I would like to move the *src-text* to *dest-text* where uid equals pid.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE dest_table 
SET dest_table.dest-text = source_table.source-text, 
WHERE source_table.pid = dest_table.pid
```

Thanks!

Emil

Answer (score 1):

You simply want `join`.  The proper syntax in MySQL is:

```
UPDATE dest_table d JOIN
       source_table s
       ON s.pid = d.pid
    SET d.dest_text = s.source_text;
```

Hyphens in identifiers are not allowed.  If you really do have hyphens then you need to escape the name:

```
UPDATE dest_table d JOIN
       source_table s
       ON s.pid = d.pid
    SET d.`dest-text` = s.`source-text`;
```